# Como puedo obtener, la hora desde Razor ASP.NET

Tags: .net

En esta ocacion vengo una duda la cual es, como puedo obtener la hora o la hora desde Razor o una manera de obtenerlas de modo separado, adjunto mi Cls entidad y la View, gracias y disculpen la molestia.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


    namespace model.entity
    {
       public class Cursos
        {
            private int _IdCursos;

            public int IdCursos
            {
                get { return _IdCursos; }
                set { _IdCursos = value; }
            }
            private string _Nombre;

            public string Nombre
            {
                get { return _Nombre; }
                set { _Nombre = value; }
            }
            private int _IdProfesor;

            public int IdProfesor
            {
                get { return _IdProfesor; }
                set { _IdProfesor = value; }
            }
           [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            private DateTime  _FechaInicio;

            public DateTime FechaInicio
            {
                get { return _FechaInicio; }
                set { _FechaInicio = value; }
            }
           [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            private DateTime _FechaFinal;

            public DateTime FechaFinal
            {
                get { return _FechaFinal; }
                set { _FechaFinal = value; }
            }
           [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            private DateTime _HoraInicio;       

            public DateTime HoraInicio
            {
                get { return _HoraInicio; }
                set { _HoraInicio = value; }
            }
           [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            private DateTime _HoraFinal;

            public DateTime HoraFinal
            {
                get { return _HoraFinal; }
                set { _HoraFinal = value; }
            }
            private string _Notas;

            public string Notas
            {
                get { return _Notas; }
                set { _Notas = value; }
            }
            public Cursos()
            { 
            }
            public void Curzos(int idCursos, string Nombre, int idProfesor, DateTime fechaInicio, DateTime fechaFin, DateTime horaInicio, DateTime horafinal, string _notas)
            {
                this._IdCursos = idCursos;
                this._Nombre = Nombre;
                this._IdProfesor = idProfesor;
                this._FechaInicio = fechaInicio;
                this._FechaFinal = fechaFin;
                this.HoraInicio = horaInicio;
                this.HoraFinal = horafinal;
                this.Notas = Notas;
            }

        }
    }
```

---

```
@model model.entity.Cursos

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Eliminar";
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Eliminar</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Crear", "Curso", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <div>
         <div>
            <text> ID Cursos</text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IdCursos)
        </div>
        <div>
            <text> Nombre</text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>
        <div>
            <text> Id Profesor </text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IdProfesor)
        </div>
        <div>
            <text>Fecha Inicio  </text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaInicio, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
        </div>
        <div>
           <text> Fecha Final </text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaFinal, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
        </div>
        <div>
            <text> Hora Inicio </text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HoraInicio)    
        </div>
        <div>
            <text> Hora Final </text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HoraFinal)
        </div>
        <div>
            <text> Notas </text>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notas)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Eliminar</button>
        <a href="#" id="bus">Buscar</a>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: La hora actual? U hora que viene en tu modelo?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera la hora Actual amigo :D

Comment: Bastaría con un `@DateTime.Now` en tu **cshtml**... Prueba y nos comentas

Comment: Si lo que quieres es ponerlo en tu textbox basta con un Value="@DateTime.Now"

Comment: Cabe destacar que `@DateTime.Now` toma la hora del servidor, no de la maquina del usuario

Comment: @JuankGlezz Es cierto lo que me comentas, ya que lo puede, de otro modo lo hice  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HoraInicio.TimeOfDay) . Me manda la hora pero vacía.

Comment: Te dejo una referencia quizá pueda orientarte https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers

Comment: Si quieres que la hora de inicio se igual a lo hora actual debes ponerle ese valor por defecto en el modelo

Answer (score 0):

En un bloque de código puede llamar a la fecha y hora actual de la clase DateTime

```
@{ 
   string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; 
   var now = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
}
```